# What is the radius of a given circle of latitude?

Tags: spheres, spherical-geometry

I have a sphere with some latitude parallels in its northern hemisphere. I know the radius of the sphere, and I know the radius of each of the latitude parallels. I also know the distance between all of the parallels.

The problem is, I can't find a correct method of determining the actual latitude values of the parallels.

Another way of looking at this is to say, what is the radius of a given circle of latitude?

Comment: Looking at a cross-section of the sphere by a plane through the axis through the poles shows that the radius of parallel of latitude $\phi$ is $r = R \cos \phi$, where $R$ is the radius of the sphere. Equivalently, $\phi = \arccos \frac{r}{R}$.

Comment: I've just tested this using the values I have for R and r, and I'm quite satisfied that this is the correct method. Thanks muchly! Feel free to post as answer instead of just comment, and I'll mark it as right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at a cross-section of the sphere by a plane through the axis through the poles shows that the radius of the parallel of latitude $\phi$ is
$$r = R \cos \phi,$$
where $R$ is the radius of the sphere. Equivalently,
$$\phi = \pm \arccos \frac{r}{R} .$$